# Parent collection excluding children tuples with members of 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I have three point coordinates defined as tuples. In each point the values of x,y,z are either all of type 'float' or type 'NoneType'.

```
p1 =(x1,y1,z1)
p2 =(x2,y2,z2)
p3 =(x3,y3,z3)
```

I now need to create a master collection that ONLY contains those points with float values. ie exclude point tuples with 'NoneType' member values.
ie if p1,p2,p3 all contain values of type 'float' then my allPoints collection would be

```
allPoints =(p1,p2,p3)
```

If p1 has x,y,z values of type 'NoneType' then

```
 allPoints =(p2,p3)
```

Whats the most efficient way to create my allPoints collection?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "What is the best way?" is simply a wrapper around "give me code/design to solve this problem" -- which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
We expect you to attempt a solution first ... which is quite straightforward in this case.

Comment: Are you generating these tuples in the first place? If so, instead of making an empty one be `(None, None, None)` just make it `None`.

Answer (score 1):

use built-in `all()`

```
all_points = (p for p in [p1, p2, p3] if all(p))
```

This will return a generator which you can always cast it to a `tuple`, or do it on the fly:

```
all_points = tuple(p for p in [p1, p2, p3] if all(p))
```